# Removing a nasty virus from my computer

Tags: windows-7, firefox, virus, facebook

I have opened a link on my FaceBook and downloaded an executable file, unfortunately i run this file, now my browser automatically opens a new tabs that go to some one site which contains a counter like this photo:

[image]

then this site redirects me to the adfly site. also this virus makes an icon in the task bar called "Shutdown Windows" when i right click this icon i have three options Restore, Minimize and Exit. Exit makes my computer shutdown!!

How to remove this virus?

I'm using Win7

Comment: Go to http://ninite.com, download Avira and Malware bytes and let both programs take care of it.
You could also check if you can do a system restore to a date before you installed the virus. It greatly  depends on what virus it exactly is whether this option would be successful.

Comment: You're going to get a lot of recommendations for different things, only follow one of those recommendations. Personally I'd say malwarebytes to start, but once you get malware you might as well back up what you can and just wipe the machine for ease of mind.

Answer (score 1):

To remove most adds use:

- [AdwCleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/)
  followed by:
- [Junkware-Removal-Tool](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/junkware-removal-tool/)

To scan the computer for viruses use:

- [eset Free Antivirus Online Scanner](http://www.eset.co.uk/Antivirus-Utilities/Online-Scanner)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use combofix before anything else but Andie2302's suggestions are good too.
Note this won't work on windows 8 or 8.1 but anything below it will.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/

I've used a lot of different tools for this purpose and combofix has always done the best job imo.